# Showing images from outside folder in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to show images from outside folder in Tomcat.
For that I have done following code in `server.xml`

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

...
<Context docBase="C:\home\xrcwrn\public_html\" path="/" />
</Host>
```

But it is not showing any image from inside folder of public_html.
for accessing images I am using path 
http://localhost:8082/img/aa.jpg

Comment: Does public_html have a "img" subdirectory ?

Comment: @AlexisHassler Yes there is

Comment: Try to double the backslashes : <Context docBase="C:\\home\\xrcwrn\\public_html\\" path="/" />

Comment: @AlexisHassler Not working

Comment: Try with an empty path : path=""

Comment: No not working       .

Comment: Have you dropped the ROOT directory in webapps ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71469/discussion-between-alexis-hassler-and-xrcwrn).

Comment: So was this one ever solved?

Comment: @Stewart Yes I have created a subdomain and accessing image from there